# help for a multibrowser contentaditable div

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

UPDATE:

### You can see the code at http://jsfiddle.net/sV3us/1/

I got this function. It works with non IE browsers, but IE9 is not working.
I'm calling this function with 
execCommandOnElement(testDiv, "insertHTML", "some content")

```
function execCommandOnElement(el, commandName, value) {
    if (typeof value == "undefined") {
        value = null;
    }

    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        // Non-IE case

        // Temporarily enable designMode so that
        // document.execCommand() will work
        document.designMode = "on";

        //place caret
        selection.collapse (anchorNode, anchorOffset);
        selection.extend( focusNode, focusOffset);

        // Execute the command
        document.execCommand(commandName, false, value);

        // Disable designMode
        document.designMode = "off";

    } 
    else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    close_modal (); 
        // IE case
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        document.execCommand(commandName, false, value);
    }
}
```

I dont need to select something in my content editable div (for example to bold a text), I just need that IE pastes the HTML where the caret is placed. Because I need to use dialog box to get some content to paste, I use this function to know where to place it.

```
//launch
$(".launch_modal").click(function() {
   open_modal ( $(this).attr( 'data-modal' ) );

    selection = window.getSelection() ; 
    anchorNode = selection.anchorNode;
    anchorOffset = selection.anchorOffset;
    focusNode = selection.focusNode;
    focusOffset = selection.focusOffset;               
});
```

I really appreciate your help. I have been in this all day.

Comment: ok, so ar you getting a specific error in IE9?

Comment: When I clik on the Submit button, the dialog closes, but there is nothing in the editable div and this div is surrounded by 6 squares, ready to by resized.

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this please

Comment: @Ibu http://jsfiddle.net/sV3us/ Please let me know if that's ok. I clean the not important parts and omit css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave you [code to help with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726579/insert-html-when-the-caret-was-in-a-content-editable-div/6727472#6727472) yesterday. Perhaps you didn't realise that saving the caret position is exactly the same as saving the selection? Also, you don't need what the `execCommandOnElement()` function is doing for you: the stuff with enabling `designMode` is only for dealing with non-editable content, so you can remove this function entirely and just use `document.execCommand()`.

One reason your code won't work is that IE 9 does support `window.getSelection()` but does not support the non-standard `extend()` method of the selection.

Here's an example of what I think you want:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmd3A/2/

Code:

```
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE 9 and non-IE
    saveSelection = function() {
        var sel = window.getSelection(), ranges = [];
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                ranges.push(sel.getRangeAt(i));
            }
        }
        return ranges;
    };

    restoreSelection = function(savedSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        for (var i = 0, len = savedSelection.length; i < len; ++i) {
            sel.addRange(savedSelection[i]);
        }
    };
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8
    saveSelection = function() {
        var sel = document.selection;
        return (sel.type != "None") ? sel.createRange() : null;
    };

    restoreSelection = function(savedSelection) {
        if (savedSelection) {
            savedSelection.select();
        }
    };
}

var savedSel = saveSelection();

// Open the dialog...
// ...dialog closes

restoreSelection(savedSel);
try {
    document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, "<b>INSERTED</b>");
} catch (ex) {
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.pasteHTML) {
            range.pasteHTML("<b>INSERTED</b>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. This is exactly what I want. However it's not working with ie9 on my machine. Does it works in your system?

Comment: @earlyriser: Sorry, I forgot that IE doesn't support the `InsertHTML` command. I've updated my answer with an IE alternative.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This is the solution.