# execCommand insertHTML breaks stored window.getSelection()

Tags: getselection, execcommand, inserthtml

When using methods of selecting text and restoring selected text in a page, I have found that running `execCommand('insertHTML...` inbetween causes the stored selection to break.

This is a sample of how the text is selected and restored.

```
// Get Selection
 var sel = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
 // Clear Selections 
 window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
 // Restore Selection 
 window.getSelection().addRange(sel)
```

This works fine, however once you run `execCommand('insertHTML..` the selections `endOffset` sets itself to the same value as the selections `startOffset`

Is there a reason for this? More importantly is there a way round this?

---

A full example of the bug, complete with some basic console logging can be seen here.
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Y8pJ7/

The objective of this fiddle is to select text , transform it to uppercase and then reselect the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How best to save and restore the selection really depends on what you're doing. For your specific example, where existing text is just having its case transformed, I'd suggest a character index-based approach, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596688/96100 (although that answer requires Rangy, but can be trivially changed not to require it: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8pJ7/8).

For some other cases, a better approach is to use invisible marker elements at the start and end of the selection, which is the approach taken by the [selection save/restore module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule) of [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) (disclosure: I am Rangy's author).

**UPDATE 18 June 2012**

Rangy now has character offset-based save and restore of selections and ranges via a new [TextRange module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) ([demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html)).

Comment: Really nice Tim, thanks for taking the time to hook up my fiddle.