# How to restore caret position after paste to contenteditable and sanitization?

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, contenteditable, caret, sanitize

I have a `<div>` that has `contenteditable="true"` and after paste I'm sanitizing pasted content with [Sanitize.js](https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js). The problem is, of course, that after Sanitization the cursor is put on the start of the div. How can I put cursor position after the pasted content?

HTML:
`<div contentEditable="true" id="ce"></div>`

JS from Sanitize.js examples (modified):

```
function do_sanitize(){
    var elm = document.getElementById('ce');
    var cfg = Sanitize.Config.RELAXED;
    // Create new Sanitize object
    var s = new Sanitize(cfg);
    var cleaned_html = s.clean_node(elm);
    // Prepare container for sanitized HTML and append it
    var clean_container = document.getElementById('ce');
    while(clean_container.childNodes.length > 0) {
    clean_container.removeChild(clean_container.firstChild);
  }
  clean_container.appendChild(cleaned_html);
}
```

Comment: I'm working on and have nearly finished a character-index based solution for this in [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy). In the meantime, you may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841644/96100