# Highlight part of the formatted textarea or div text from and to specified position in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, textarea, selection, highlight

I have pretty good function that do what I need, but in IE it doesn't consider linebreaks and, maybe, some other stuff.

The function is next:

```
    this.createSelection = function (field, start, end) {
        if (field.createTextRange) {
            var selRange = field.createTextRange();
            selRange.collapse(true);
            selRange.moveStart('character', start);
            selRange.moveEnd('character', end - start);
            selRange.select();
        } else if (field.setSelectionRange) {
            field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (field.selectionStart) {
            field.selectionStart = start;
            field.selectionEnd = end;
        }
        field.focus();
    }
```

It needs to be modified in two points:

1. Highlight correct part of the text with linebreaks and other stuff.
2. Highlight not only inside textarea, but even in div, p, span etc.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've published a function many times on Stack Overflow that does this for textareas and text inputs, handling line breaks correctly. Here's an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373056/96100

Doing the same for selections within regular HTML elements is trickier, and also less well-defined. Here's an answer about this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841644/96100