# Why doesn't the document.execCommand work when I click on a div?

Tags: javascript, html

Both the button and the div have the same 'onclick' code, yet the execCommand only seems to work on the button. Is there any way I can make it work when pressing the div?

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/ZzL8y/

```
<button onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);">Bold</button>
<div onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);" style='border:1px solid black;width:50px;'>Bold</div>

<div id='input' contenteditable='true'>
    select some of this text and then hit one of the buttons above
</div>
```

​

Comment: Im guessing it doesn't work with the div because you lose focus and selection. With the button the focus is kept.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to prevent the `mousedown` event on your div because it steals the focus:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzL8y/5/)

Comment: brilliant konstantin!

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/ZzL8y/4/
This is not the complete answer but these links might help you:-

1> [set execcommand just for a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205544/set-execcommand-just-for-a-div)

2> [select all text in contenteditable div when it focus/click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805852/select-all-text-in-contenteditable-div-when-it-focus-click)

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, it's necessary to set contenteditable = true before execCommand.

For IE it is not necessary.