# document.execCommand('bold') not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

REACT JS :
im trying to make simple editor for my project ,
which can make text bold , italic and underline

im using contentEditable

```
<div className="inputBox" contentEditable>some text here to play with</div>
```

and im using a button just above it to make text bold

```
<div className="button' onClick={this.buttonCLick.bind(this)}>BOLD</div>
```

which calls this onclick

```
buttonCLick(){
        let isWorking = document.execCommand('bold',false,'');
        console.log('isWorking:', isWorking);
    }
```

but the "`isWorking`" return `false` every time and nothing happns to selected text .

Answer (score 0):

What browser shows this behavior? Have you tried that on different browser?

E.g. on Firefox you must make sure that default font-weight is 400 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=948411). Here I have have reported documentation bug for Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1515267

Another exotic case seems to be this, but I have not reproduced that:  [Why doesn't the document.execCommand work when I click on a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525087/why-doesnt-the-document-execcommand-work-when-i-click-on-a-div) but