# execCommand does not work with a div as a event listener

Tags: javascript

I been looking all over on google and I cant seem to find a working solution for this situation. I basically want to use a div call trigger to successfully execute document.execCommand(); but I notice that document.execCommand() don't work with a

div as a event listener and I know this works with a button tag but I don't want to use a button with this so how can I get this working with a div and I know one of you guys will say, you know you don't need to use document.execCommand to do something like this

and I am aware of that but for personal reasons I need to do this with a div with document.execCommand.

My code

```js
document.querySelector('#trigger').addEventListener('click',underline);

function underline(){
  
  document.execCommand('underline', false, '');
  
}
```

```css
#trigger{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='trigger'></div><!--</trigger>-->

<p>Text highlight the word Adam and press the red trigger to add a underline to Adam.</p>

<p contenteditable='true'>Adam</p>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the range etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your response and what do you mean by range?

Comment: why not use css selector: ​
 text-decoration: underline ?

Comment: I removed answer. Sorry I need to fix it.

Comment: Just like the post said I need to find a way to get this to work with document.execCommand() with a div I know there is other ways to do this but I need to do this. This way and ok take your time. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: To be clear, are you eventually hoping for the user to select text and click to underline?

Comment: Yeah basically the process would go like this. Text highlight the word Adam first and then press the red div to underline the word Adam.

Comment: Example that works -> [codepen](https://codepen.io/chrisdavidmills/pen/gzYjag)

Comment: Thanks for your response @James but are you able to give a code example based on my code? I look at that already and that seem confusing to break down and i'm trying to avoid using onclick and I need to use a event listener if you don't know how that's ok. I'm just glad that you also tried to help me out as well.

Comment: So here is the issue. The command works against the `selection`. When you trigger the command from a button, it does not cancel the `selection`. and indeed, changing your trigger to a `button` and it works. So you would need to record a selected range, and then re-apply that as part of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should make it work try this out.

```js
document.querySelector("#trigger").addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){event.preventDefault();});
document.querySelector('#trigger').addEventListener('click',underline);

function underline(){
  
  document.execCommand('underline', false, '');
  
}
```

```css
#trigger{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='trigger'></div><!--</trigger>-->

<p>Text highlight the word Adam and press the red trigger to add a underline to Adam.</p>

<p contenteditable='true'>Adam</p>
```

I took ideas from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525087/why-doesnt-the-document-execcommand-work-when-i-click-on-a-div) and I converted this method into a event listener version for your situation.