# How is styling being applied on selected characters of the string- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I came across rich text editor in [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YYvCQwKc3VnmfcgF5g2d?p=preview) and wanted to know how exactly is the code able to understand that a particular `element` has to be decorated with `bold` styling ?

The `$container.html()` shows proper styling in `console` but how it knows which part of string was selected for styling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that plunkr is using a HTML5 feature called `contenteditable`. In short this attribute turns a html element (usually a div) into something that can act like a textarea, but you're editing the actual html on the page.
As for the selected styling the Bold button is using `Document.execCommand` to apply a command to the current selection.

Here's a tutorial on getting started with contenteditable and execCommand: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-wysiwyg-editor-with-the-contenteditable-attribute--cms-25657. Hope that helps.

PS I updated the link in the other question you commented on.